# how can i solve this attribute error in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, attributes, seaborn

I have this attribute error when I run the program. may I know the reason?

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'distplot' (most likely due to a circular import)

this is the code I wrote

```py
from numpy import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.displot(random.normal(size=1000), hist=False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: What's the full stack trace?

Comment: The [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) show that it is deprecated. It depends what version you're using

Comment: In your question you write `distplot`, but in the code you write `displot` (without the `t`). They are related but different functions.  `displot` is new since Seaborn 0.11, which also deprecated `distplot`.  Possibly you are running an older version of Seaborn.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
from numpy import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.distplot(random.normal(size=1000), hist=False)

plt.show()
```

Code modified by me:

```
sns.displot(x) -> sns.distplot(o)
```

This is output:

[image]